# PHPexcel Library Error when exporting from database

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am using the PHPexcel Library for my reporting. It functions well when I'm using static values but, when I try to export my data in MySQL database to PHPexcel,

it always gives me this error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

I've tried `ob_start()` function but the moment i opened my downloaded excel, it is empty

this is my PHPexcel code:

```
<?php

include("conn.php");

$query ="Select * from info";
$result = mysql_query($query);



/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();




// Add some data
$row1=1;
$row2=1;
$row3=1;

echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some data\n";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$let1 = "A".$row1."";
$let2 = "B".$row2."";
$let3 = "C".$row3."";

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let1, $row['id']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let2, $row['name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let3, $row['age']);

$row1++;
$row2++;
$row3++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:C1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:C1")->getFont()->setSize(20);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:C1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
        )
    )
);


header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

exit();

?>
```

It works perfect dealing with static values but when I tried to dynamically add values, it messes up. Please help, thank u in advance

Comment: If you have anything above PHP, be it a space, a cookie, sessions, it could cause this. A byte order mark will also cause this.

Comment: i dont have any other code above my php... it just pure php, no sessions, no cookie

Comment: Try and put your headers then, underneath your opening `<?php` tag. Or try the answer given below.

Comment: You are `echo`-ing all kinds of debug information to the browser, like `echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";`. Remove that. _only_ output the excel file.

Comment: If you want to see what and where is sending the headers then use     headers_sent($file, $line)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your code, your header() calls are saying that the content of the page should be treated as a spreadsheet but you do not create any output from your spreadsheet object. Remove all output (your echo calls) as it's not possible to have it, move your header calls to the top of the file and echo out the raw output from your Excel class.

Code below. I've moved the headers, stripped some junk and added what the PHPExcel manual suggests is the way to write to STDOUT.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"filename.xlsx\"");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** Include path **/
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

include("conn.php");

$query ="Select * from info";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Add some data
$row1=1;
$row2=1;
$row3=1;

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $let1 = "A".$row1."";
    $let2 = "B".$row2."";
    $let3 = "C".$row3."";

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let1, $row['id']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let2, $row['name']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($let3, $row['age']);

    $row1++;
    $row2++;
    $row3++;
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:C1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:C1")->getFont()->setSize(20);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:C1');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000')
        )
    )
);

// Untested... pulled from the manual as the way to write with PHPExcel
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');                                                                                                           
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

Comment: I tried to remove the echo and put ob_start() again... it managed to be downloaded but again when i open the excel file error pop up

Comment: See my edit above. I've refactored your code and added a write to stdout. May need some tweaking as I'm only going by the manual - I've barely used PHPExcel before.

Comment: As I stated in a comment above, this line `ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');` has a semi-colon in `';../Classes/'` which I am pretty sure needs to be a colon.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Semicolon is the path separator for Windows environments whereas colon is used on *nix. Technically it should use the PATH_SEPARATOR constant - ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').PATH_SEPARATOR.'../Classes/');

Comment: Thanks for a great effor sir to help but still having an error the moment i opened my excel it says "excel cannot open file because the format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches" im using MS EXCEL 2007

Comment: @Bongsky - my bad, you needed php://output. I've edited the last line of the code in the above post to reflect this. I've hacked together an example based on yours, without the DB stuff, and it's producing a spreadsheet that opens in Excel 2010. One tip... any errors in the PHP will be obscured by the fact the output downloads to a file. Comment out the header() calls until you start seeing a bunch of junk in your browser - this is the raw spreadsheet. Then add the header() calls back in.

Comment: @phil-lavin Thanks... It works now... ;) ur a JOB saver

Comment: Great news. Glad to see a Happy Ending once again. `+1` well-deserved. Good work Phil.